# MySQL: Group result set by n groups

Tags: mysql-5.7, group-by

How do I group a result set from a query into n groups?

In my particular case, I want to spit the result into 10 groups so I can do some `SUM` and `AVG` on each group.

For example, if I ran this query:

```
SELECT
    `user`,
    COUNT(`user`) AS `times_banked`,
    SUM(`token_change`) AS `tokens_banked`,
    AVG(`token_change`) AS `average_single_bank`
FROM `wp_tokens_log`
WHERE `action` = 'yeokens_banked'
    AND `day` BETWEEN '2018-05-31' AND '2019-05-31'
GROUP BY `user`
ORDER BY `times_banked` DESC
```

In my case, it returns ~250K rows and I want to group the top ~25K rows then the next ~25K rows and so on.

Ideally, I'm looking for a query that doesn't have to be changed based on the number of rows in the set and bonus points if a query can take any number (n) to do the grouping. For example, if I wanted to now get 20 groups rather than 10.

Comment: You may enumerate the records (for example, using variable), then divide this number by groups amount and select records by reminder value.